# Firefox: run functions from Javascript through an extension

Tags: firefox, scripting, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

At the present I'm pasting a Javascript into the console of FF and I'm calling the functions from the console:

```
function fill (i){
    if(i==1){
        SINGLE_START();
    }
    else if(i==2){
        DUAL_START();
    }
    else if(i==3){
        INTEGRATED_START();
    }
    else{
        alert("=======================\n               Tool Filler\n=======================\n\n1 or 2");
    }
}
```

It is used to **scrape** the content of the website and e.g. create a file or generate an email from certain parts of the website, e.g.:

```
function SINGLE_START(){
    
    //Focus:
    let d = $(document).activeElement.contentDocument.activeElement.contentDocument.activeElement.contentDocument;
```

etc.

I thougt, there could be a way to use it through an extension and so I installed Tampermonkey and saved the script as userscript within the extension. But than I have a problem that I'm not able to call the desired function from the script as I need it, not just start the script as the website loads.

Does anyone has an idea how to call the functions one by one from within Tampermonkey (or Greasemonkey), or any other extension?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Tampermonkey scripts run in isolated context. There are two kinds:

#### 1. No special privilegies

If you're not using any special GM functions that are unlocked by `@grant GM_doThisAndThat` and instead you use `@grant none`, then what internally happens is something like this:

```
function TheScript() {
     // Here is your script that you added to tampermonkey
}
TheScript();
```

This if you have a function there, it is only available in the script. You need to explicitly expose it to window context:

```
function fill (i){
    ... code here ...
}
window.myFill = fill;
```

Then in console you write `myFill(42)` and it will execute.

I would recommend that you avoid assigning `fill` to window since it's a name that could likely conflict with something, but that's up to you.

#### 2. Special privilegies

If you're using some of the GM features, you need to add `@grant unsafeWindow` and then assign to `unsafeWindow` variable. **Be careful what you expose like this, you don't want to allow the website to access any of the `GM_function` features as they could access your private data on other websites and your computer!**